# Trying to read Japanese CSV file in Java

Tags: shift-jis

I am trying to read a Japanese content CSV file which is downloaded and extracted pragmatically.

Code to read the CSV

```
  String splitBy = ",";
            BufferedReader br;// = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathOfExcel + "\\KEN_ALL.CSV   "));
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathOfExcel + "\\KEN_ALL1.CSV"),"SHIFT-JIS")); 
              String line = "";
              int cnt = 0;
              while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                  //System.out.println("Count :: " + cnt++);
                  List<Object> excelList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                  if(line != null){
                   String[] splitCells = line.split(splitBy);
                   excelList.add(splitCells[0].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[1].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[2].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[3].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[4].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[5].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[6].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[7].replace("\"", ""));
                   excelList.add(splitCells[8].replace("\"", ""));
                   returnList.add(excelList);
                 }
              }
              br.close();
```

I have tried both UTF-8 and SHIFT-JIS as shown in the following code.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathOfExcel + "\\KEN_ALL1.CSV"),"UTF-8"));
```

When I was trying to encode with UTF-8 and SHIFT-JIS the `" excelList.add(splitCells[3].replace("\"", ""));"` will be returning the following outputs. But where as the original output should be **ﾎｯｶｲﾄﾞｳ**

UTF-8 - Î¯¶²ÄÞ³

Shift-JIS - ﾃ篠ｯﾂｶﾂｲﾃ�楪ｳ

Comment: Any question with this title needs to be upvoted :D

Answer (score 0):

The file `KEN_ALL1.CSV` is the file provided by JAPAN POST Co.,Ltd., right?
https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/dl/kogaki-zip.html

I could read the file collectly with your program, so I think the program has no problem.

[image: Result of your program on my Eclipse console]

I think your file might have some problem. Can you read the CSV file with text editor that can show the character encoding of the file (e.g. Notepad++)? Is the content of the file showed collectly, and is the character encoding really Shift-JIS like this?

[image: KEN_ALL1.CSV shown in Notepad++]